# Pass variable to JS and Output it in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, html-table

if got a dynamic generated table (php foreach) that has an id it. I want to pass the ID of the clicked row to a JS function and output it inside a popup. The Popup also opens by clicking on the selected row.

Input from HTML

```
                <form>
                    <tr onclick="dialogOeffnen('loslegen-dialog')">
                    <td>
                      <span id="id_element"><?php echo $row["ID"];?></span><br>
                    </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Vorname"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Nachname"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Vorname2"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Nachname2"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Vorname3"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Nachname3"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Vorname4"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Nachname4"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <span id="title_element"><?php echo $row["Titel"];?></span><br>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Standort"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Klasse"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Beginn"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Abgabe"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center><a href=<?php echo "uploads/" . $FileActualName?>">Link</a></center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Genehmigt"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["Erstellt"] . "<br>"; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("dialog_title").innerText = document.getElementById("id_element").innerText;
function dialogOeffnen(dialogId) {
    document.getElementById(dialogId).classList.add("sichtbar");
    document.getElementById("body-overlay").classList.add("sichtbar");
}

function dialogSchliessen(dialogId) {
    document.getElementById(dialogId).classList.remove("sichtbar");
    document.getElementById("body-overlay").classList.remove("sichtbar");
}
```

Output here

```
<div class="dialog" id="loslegen-dialog">
   <a href="#" role="button" class="dialog-schließen-button" onclick="dialogSchliessen('loslegen-dialog')">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
   </a>
   <div class="textarea">
   <h1 id="dialog_title"></h1>
```

My suggestion was, giving the span of the ID an id="id_element" and pass it to JS. However the output does only display the first ID of my table no matter which row im clicking.

Comment: `id`s must be unique, yours aren't

Comment: You're missing a `<table>` in your first code

Comment: But how do I solve this? I know I can do id="id_element $row['ID]" in the span, but that doesnt work for me either.

Comment: why doesn't that work? It would make the IDs unique

Comment: @brombeer thats only a cutout of my code :) <table> is there

Comment: `id_element $row['ID]` is an invalid value for an `id` attribute - no spaces

Comment: _If_ `<table>` is there it's at the wrong place. Place your `<form>` around your table or inside a `<td>`. `<form>` is not allowed inside `<table>`

Comment: Good point. An underscore would be a good way to fix the space issue

Comment: @ADyson, if I do id="id_element $row['ID]", do I need to add document.getElementById("id_element $row['ID]").innerText; in JS?

Comment: No. It would probably be better to pass the ID into the dialogOffnen function as an extra parameter, via `onclick="dialogOeffnen('loslegen-dialog')`, e.g. `onclick="dialogOeffnen('loslegen-dialog', <?php echo $row["ID"];?>)`. Then within that function you can have `function dialogOeffnen(dialogId, rowId) { document.getElementById("dialog_title").innerText = rowId;`. Then actually you don't even need to bother with `id_element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're dealing with passing data to JavaScript via HTML elements, the best approach is to set a `data-*` attribute:

```html
<span class="id_element" data-id="<?=$row['ID']?>">this is my ID: <?=$row["ID"]?></span><br>
```

And in JavaScript you can simply access it via `myElement.dataset.id`.

In your case, instead of sending a name of an element to your function, you can send the row element itself, and simply search for its child element to get the id element:

```
<tr onclick="dialogOeffnen(this)">
  <td>
    <span class="id_element"><?=$row["ID"]?></span><br>
  </td>
```

```js
const elBodyOverlay = document.getElementById("body-overlay"),
      elDialogTitle = document.getElementById("dialog_title"),
      elLoslegenDialog = document.getELementById("loslegen-dialog");

function dialogOeffnen(elRow) {
    //find our "id" element
    const elId = elRow.querySelector(".id_element");
    //display ID in the popup
    elDialogTitle.innerText = elId.textContent;
    //open popup
    elLoslegenDialog.classList.add("sichtbar");
    elBodyOverlay.classList.add("sichtbar");
}
```

However, a better solution is to simply send the ID itself instead:

```
<tr onclick="dialogOeffnen('<?=$row["ID"]?>')">
  <td>
    <span class="id_element"><?=$row["ID"]?></span><br>
  </td>
```

```js
const elBodyOverlay = document.getElementById("body-overlay"),
      elDialogTitle = document.getElementById("dialog_title"),
      elLoslegenDialog = document.getElementById("loslegen-dialog");

function dialogOeffnen(id) {
    //display ID
    elDialogTitle.innerText = id;
    //open popup
    elLoslegenDialog.classList.add("sichtbar");
    elBodyOverlay.classList.add("sichtbar");
}
```

Note that `<span>` changed attribute `id` to `class`, this allows you to use the same name on multiple elements.

Comment: Thanks for that! I changed my code to your suggestions, but still cant get the ID displayed. Could you explain what to do with that "myElement.dataset.id" ? I just started coding and got no clue on JS yet... Do I need to insert the JS function you are showing to the others? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Maximilian I've updated the answer.  Also, for better performance, cache elements in variables and use these variables instead of `document.get*` functions.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, names are in german, so I was skipping reading them...updated the answer again.

Comment: So, the idea behind of using `data-*` attributes, is that you can store data from PHP inside an element, which will be independent from information displayed on screen. And in JS in your particular case you'd use `elId.dataset.id` instead of `elId.textContent`

Comment: I think there is another issue somewhere. The Popup is still not showing up with your code. I'm wondering why, because you've done everything like in the former code to show the popup. I keep on trying. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello Sir, I've found it! You had a typo on getElementById.
The popup couldn't open because of the big L.
"elLoslegenDialog = document.getELementById("loslegen-dialog");"
Big thanks for your time and help! you made my day :)